# display images using servlets

Tags: java, swing, servlets, jfreechart

I have a scenario where I need to display tables(generated using JTable) converted it into a png image and then display them using servlets.

The following is the code in the servlet to display the table :

```
{
        table = u.generateTableChart("datamonth");    
        saveToServlet(table, table.getTableHeader(), p_resp);
}

void saveToServlet(JTable table, JTableHeader header,
            HttpServletResponse p_resp)
    {

        int w = Math.max(table.getWidth(), header.getWidth());
        int h = table.getHeight() + header.getHeight();
        OutputStream out = null;
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
        header.paint(g2);
        g2.translate(0, header.getHeight());
        table.paint(g2);
        g2.dispose();
        try {
            p_resp.setContentType("image/png");
            out = p_resp.getOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bi, "png", out);

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("write: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

This seems to be throwing this error when I try to view it on the web page 
The image cannot be displayed as it has too many errors.

I am able to store the file in a temporary location and I am able to see the graph.

For Charts generated using JFreeCharts I am using this :

```
 ServletOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        out = p_resp.getOutputStream();
        p_resp.setContentType("image/png");
        chart=u.genarateLineChart(m_martiniInstance);
        ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(out, chart, 625, 500); 
    }
```

and still not luck

Thanks in advance,
Bhavya

Comment: on which platform (Windows, Linux) is your server?

Comment: @SJuan the tomcat server is on RHEL

Comment: @Bhavya: Are you sure that the image is in RGB format? this error  usually occurs if the image you are generating is not meant for screen consumption.

Comment: can you try to download the file instead of viewing it? I remember some trouble when using graphic libraries from java launched from Linux console because the X libraries were not loaded.

Answer (score 3):

I think problem is you are setting content type as `"image/png"` but writing jpeg `writeChartAsJPEG` 
use

```
ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(...)
```

Comment: @Prashanth i changed the code and to check this. This does not seem to be helping either

Comment: normally responses are cached from browser use ctrl+F5 to fully reload, or delete browser cache and try to reload image

Comment: I am able to view the line chart using the code provided but not the Jtable, any answers to that ?

Comment: suggest you raise it as a separate Question to nail it !